# Failing to load extension in a headless puppeteer session

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-extension, puppeteer

I am trying to load an extension ([I dont care about cookies](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/i-dont-care-about-cookies/fihnjjcciajhdojfnbdddfaoknhalnja)) into chrome using puppeteer. The manifest file and the rest of the extension is in the directory

```
./chrome-extensions/fihnjjcciajhdojfnbdddfaoknhalnja/3.4.9_0
```

inside the project itself.
I am loading this particular extension only disabling all others just in case.

Next step I am opening a page and want to navigate to the extension within the chrome session.

This is done in various ways on different systems it seems. On MacOS this looks like

```
'chrome://extensions/?id=fihnjjcciajhdojfnbdddfaoknhalnja'
```

but I am running puppeteer on a headless ubuntu / Linux machine remotely.

When I run the code below it fails at going to the extension link.

What is the correct link to the extension in chrome/Ubuntu/Linux?

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const idontcarecookies = './chrome-extensions/fihnjjcciajhdojfnbdddfaoknhalnja/3.4.9_0'
puppeteer.launch({ headless: true, devtools: true,
args: [
    '--disable-extensions-except=${idontcarecookies}',
    '--load-extension=${idontcarecookies}'
        ] }).then(async (browser) => {
try {
    console.log('==>Navigate to Extension');
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    // Navigate to extension page
    //    await page.goto('chrome-extension://fihnjjcciajhdojfnbdddfaoknhalnja/panel.html');
    await page.goto('chrome://extensions/?id=fihnjjcciajhdojfnbdddfaoknhalnja');
    // Take a screenshot of the extension page
    console.log('==>Take Screenshot');
    await page.screenshot({path: 'chrome-extension.png'});
    await browser.close();
    console.log(`All done`);
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit();
} finally {
    browser.close();
}
});
```

This is the error I am getting back however I change the Url to the Extension

```
==>Navigate to Extension
Error: net::ERR_INVALID_URL at chrome://extensions/?id=fihnjjcciajhdojfnbdddfaoknhalnja
at navigate (/pathproject/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/FrameManager.js:120:37)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
at async FrameManager.navigateFrame (/pathproject/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/FrameManager.js:94:17)
at async Frame.goto (/pathproject/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/FrameManager.js:406:12)
at async Page.goto (/pathproject/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:672:12)
at async /pathproject/test-extension.js:28:5
-- ASYNC --
at Frame.<anonymous> (/pathproject/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:15)
at Page.goto (/pathproject/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:672:49)
at Page.<anonymous> (/pathproject/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:112:23)
at /pathproject/test-extension.js:28:16
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this failure is actually not that obvious.
When copying the folder of the extension to the local directory of the project make sure that the '**permissioning**' is set up correctly.

I had the permissioning set to the Chrome directory which is **root:staff** so in this case I changed it to my **username:staff** and then it started working!

I used the following args to avoid any problem with the ${}

```
      '--disable-extensions-except=chrome-extensions/idontcare',
      '--load-extension=chrome-extensions/idontcare'
```

where the folder 'idontcare' is the folder of the extension with the manifest.json in it.

And PS. going to the chrome:extensions with **headless:true** won't work. Looking up the extensions page using puppeteer only works in the **headless:false** mode. That way you can see if your extension is loaded or not (swipe bar is ON or OFF), it should automatically be ON if the directory of the extension was correctly set up.

Use

```
 await page.goto('chrome://extensions/');
```

to check extensions in headless:false mode.

Also upgrade to latest node version. I was using version 12 and the extension wasn't working, but with version 20 it was picking up the extension and it was even screenshotable in headless:"new" mode. So it's possible to check an extension is loaded using Node 20.